# Let $\rho_n (x) := n^d \rho (nx)$. Then $\rho_n * f \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f$ in $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm trying to prove a result mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164576/problem-from-breziss-book-mollifiers) thread, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $\rho \in L^1 (\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\int \rho = 1$. Let $\rho_n (x) := n^d \rho (nx)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^d$. Let $f \in L^p (\mathbb R^d)$ with $p \in [1, \infty)$. Then $\rho_n * f \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f$ in $L^p$.

Could you have a check on my below proof?

---

A sequence of *mollifiers* $(\hat \rho_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is any sequence of functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $(\int \hat \rho_n)_n$ is a constant sequence and that
$$
\hat \rho_n \in C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^d), \quad \operatorname{supp} \hat \rho_n \subset \overline{B(0, r_n)},
$$
where $r_n \to 0^+$ and $B(x, r)$ denotes an open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$. Then we have

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4677038/approximate-a-function-in-lp-mathbb-rd-by-mollifiers) Let $f \in L^p (\mathbb R^d)$ with $p \in [1, \infty)$. Then $\hat \rho_n * f \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f \int \hat \rho_1$ in $L^p$.

**Proof of the Theorem** Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. We have $\mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$ is dense in $L^1 (\mathbb R^d)$. There is $\hat \rho \in \mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\|\rho - \hat \rho\|_1 < \varepsilon$.  Let $\hat \rho_n (x) := n^d \hat \rho (nx)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^d$. Then $\int \hat \rho_n = \int \hat \rho$ for all $n$. Clearly, $(\hat \rho_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of mollifiers. By Young's inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
\| \rho_n * f- \hat\rho_n * f\|_p &= \| (\rho_n - \hat\rho_n) * f\|_p \\
&\le \| \rho_n - \hat\rho_n\|_1 \|f\|_p \\
&= \| \rho - \hat\rho\|_1 \|f\|_p \\
&\le \varepsilon \|f\|_p.
\end{align}
$$

Let $a := \int \hat \rho_1$. Then $|a- 1| = |\int \rho - \int \hat \rho| \le \varepsilon$. So
$$
\begin{align}
\| \rho_n * f- f\|_p &\le \| \rho_n * f- \hat\rho_n * f\|_p + \| \hat \rho_n * f- af\|_p + \| af- f\|_p\\
&\le 2 \varepsilon \|f\|_p +  \| \hat \rho_n * f- f\|_p.
\end{align}
$$

By above **Lemma**, $\| \hat \rho_n * f- af\|_p \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$. The claim then follows by taking the limit $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$.

Comment: all this comes under the name of approximations to the identity. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3681140/121671) is a general result for $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: The conditions $\rho\ge0$ and $\int_{\mathbb R^d} \rho=1$ are missing.

Comment: You can find this in the book of functional analysis by H Brezis

Comment: @daw Now I see why $\rho \ge 0$ is important. Thank you so much!